# How to extract element names from a XML Schema using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

This is an example snippet showing the format of the schema definition for elements:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.1">
            <xs:include schemaLocation="enumerations_schema.xsd"/>
            <xs:element name="xml_details" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="xml_element_1" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="xml_element_3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="xml_element_4" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="data_details" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="data_element_1" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Lorem ipsum</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="as_of_date" type="xs:date"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="data_element_2" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Lorem ipsum</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="data_element_3" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="data_element_4" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="Enumeration_1">
                                        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="data_element_5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="data_element_6" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

As you can see, there are two parent elements (xml_details and data_details) with multiple children. My question is how to fetch only the children element names (leaf nodes) using XSLT? The output would look something like this:

```
            xml_element_1
            xml_element_3
            xml_element_4
            data_element_1
            data_element_2
            data_element_3
            data_element_4
            data_element_5
            data_element_6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the XPath expression `//xs:element[not(.//xs:element)]/@name` you get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean like this?:

    <xsl:template match="//element[not(.//element)]"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="/@name"/>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: At least with XSLT 2.0 I would literally do `<xsl:value-of select="//xs:element[not(.//xs:element)]/@name" separator="&10;"/>`. But obviously there are many ways to work with XSLT, if you want to use templates then ` <xsl:template match="xs:element[not(.//xs:element)]"> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> </xsl:template>` is one (the leading `//` is not needed in a match pattern).

Comment: Thanks the XPath works okay on xpathfiddle.net but when I open in XML Spy or any other XML environment editor, it throws this error:
Error in XPath expression
Undefined namespace prefix - 'xs'
match="xs:element[not(.//xs:element)]"

Comment: Oxygen and i assume many more editors take the namespaces out of your input-xml by default, so you can use them in xpath-statements. maybe you have to define the ns-prefix first. search for "register namespace xpath (xmlspy)"

Comment: This doesn't seem to capture the immediate first child element of a node. e.g. data_element_1 under data_details doesn't show up on the results. Any idea?

Comment: I tested http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEv6 and the output contains `data_element_1`.